# Windows 7 Media Player won't add MP3 files

Tags: windows-7, mp3, windows-media-player

I have a set of MP3 files that Windows Media Player just refuses to add to the library.  They are placed in the standard My Music folder.  I play them in media player. They just won't be listed in the library.

I've tried dragging them and dropping them on the media player but they still don't appear in the library.

I have an identical laptop where I've also copied the mp3 files and they appear in the library fine.

Any ideas what would cause this?

Comment: Is the ID3 information of those files fine? Try correcting them with [MP3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/).

Comment: @Tom: thanks I'll take a look into that although it would seem strange that two identical machines would behave differently.

Comment: Oh, in that case you rather might want to look into resetting Windows Media Player in one or another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article describes [how to reset the Windows Media Player Library](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1045/wmp_how_to_erase_reset_correct_windows_media_library/), you could try it.

> 1. Close Microsoft Media Player for at least 30 seconds.
> 2. Click Start and then Run.
> 3. Type the following into the text box:
>
>    `%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Media Player`
> 4. Click OK and a folder showing you your library files will appear.
> 5. Erase all the files that end with `.wmdb`.
> 6. Open Microsoft Media Player.
> 7. Push <kbd>F3</kbd>.
> 8. Select the locations for your music files.
> 9. WMP will reindex your music.

Answer (score 1):

The individual files are bugged for me because I added them, then deleted them and tried to add them again.

Make a copy and add that – it will work.